How to update the Metadata for Tokenkeg, the original Solana token standard
Is it possible to update the token metadata for the Tokenkeg program?
How to do it using Javascript?

This is possible if it was marked as mutable when creating the Metadata accounts with Metaplex and if your address is set as the updateAuthority.
import {
    createGenericFile,
    keypairIdentity,
    publicKey,
    Umi,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";
import {
    clusterApiUrl,
    Connection,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
    fetchMetadataFromSeeds,
    findMasterEditionPda,
    mplTokenMetadata,
    updateV1,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";
import fs, { readFileSync } from "fs";
import path from "path";

export const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

const umi = createUmi(connection);

export const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from("UPDATE WTH SECRET KEY"));

umi.use(keypairIdentity(keypair)).use(mplTokenMetadata());

export function uint8FileData(pathName: string): Uint8Array {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, pathName);

    const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    return data;
}

async function updateSPLTokenMD() {
    const mint = publicKey(""); // update with mint address
    const onChainMetadata = await fetchMetadataFromSeeds(umi, { mint });

    const newName = "Updated Asset Name";

    const offChainMetadata = await (await fetch(onChainMetadata.uri)).json();

    const filePath = "<PATH TO YOUR IMAGE FILE>"; // update this appropriately
    let fileData = uint8FileData(filePath);
    let file = createGenericFile(fileData, filePath, {
        contentType: "image/jpeg", // update the file MIME type if different
    });

    const [image] = await umi.uploader.upload([file]);
    const uri = await umi.uploader.uploadJson({
        ...offChainMetadata,
        image,
        name: newName,
    });

    await updateV1(umi, {
        mint,
        authority: umi.identity,
        data: { ...onChainMetadata, name: newName },
        primarySaleHappened: true,
        isMutable: true,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
}

updateSPLTokenMD().then().catch();

In the example above, we update the off-chain metadata URI fields, name and image and upload that to Arweave.
We then make the changes to the on-chain data with the updateV1 method from MPLMetadata program.
read more: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/update
MPL guide: https://developers.metaplex.com/guides/javascript/how-to-create-an-spl-token-on-solana
